# Python 3.4: adding value to list if condition exists

Tags: list, python-3.x, append

i have a scenario like this one:

```
mainList = [[9,5],[17,3],[23,1],[9,2]]
secondaryList = [9,12,28,23,1,6,95]
myNewList = []

myNewList.append([[a,b] for a,b in mainList if a in secondaryList])
```

this, return me to me:

```
myNewList = [[9,5],[23,1],[9,2]]
```

but I need only the first occourance of "a". In other words I need to obtain:

```
myNewList = [[9,5],[23,1]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

First of all:

```
myNewList = []
myNewList.append([[a,b] for a,b in mainList if a in secondaryList])
```

simply is the same as

```
myNewList = [[a,b] for a,b in mainList if a in secondaryList]
```

Then: 
What you're building is functionally a python dictionary. Your two-element lists in `mainList` are the same as `dict.items()`!

So what you'd do is build a `dict` out of `mainList` (reversing it, because usually, you'd just save the *last*, not the *first* occurence):

```
mainDict = dict([reversed(mainList)])
```

Then you just make your new list:

```
myNewList = [ (key, mainDict[key]) for key in secondaryList ]
```

Comment: Does not work for me:
   mainDict = dict([reversed(secondaryList)])

   ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set to store the first elements and then check for existing the first element before adding the sub-lists  :

```
>>> seen=set()
>>> l=[]
>>> for i,j in mainList:
...    if i in secondaryList and i not in seen:
...        seen.add(i)
...        l.append([i,j])
... 
>>> l
[[9, 5], [23, 1]]
```

Or you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with specifying its `maxlen`.But note that you need to loop over your list from end to start if you want the first occourance of `a` because `deque` will keep the last insert value  :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from functools import partial

>>> d=defaultdict(partial(deque, maxlen=1))
>>> for i,j in mainList[::-1]:
...    if i in secondaryList:
...       d[i].append(j)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x7ff672706e68>, {9: deque([5], maxlen=1), 23: deque([1], maxlen=1)})
```